# C/C++ Bit Twiddling

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

in the spirit of [graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) I need to solve the following problem:

```
int x; 
int pow2; // always a positive power of 2
int sgn;  // always either 0 or 1
// ...
// ...
if(sgn == 0)
    x -= pow2;
else
    x += pow2;
```

Of course I need to avoid the conditional. So far the best I came up with is

```
x -= (1|(~sgn+1))*pow2
```

but that involves a multiplication which I also would like to avoid. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks all,

```
x -= (pow2^-sgn) + sgn
```

seems to do the trick!

Comment: When multiplication is not a problem, we have also: `x -= (1-2*sgn)*pow`, using the mapping `0 -> 1` and `1 -> -1`, which equals `x -> (1-2x)`.

Comment: once again, parentheses! the precedence of `^` is lower than `+`, so ` x -= pow2^-sgn + sgn` is `x -= pow2^(-sgn+sgn)` is `x -= pow2`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would try

```
x -= (pow2 ^ (~sgn+1)) + sgn
```

or, as suggested by lijie in the comments

```
x -= (pow2 ^ -sgn) + sgn
```

If `sgn` is `0`, `~sgn+1` is also `0`, so `pow2 ^ (~sgn+1) == pow2`.  If `sgn` is `1`, `(~sgn+1)` is `0xFFFFFFFF`, and `(pow2 ^ (~sgn+1)) + sgn == -pow2`.

Comment: you can change `~sgn+1` to `-sgn`.

Comment: oh yes. uh `^` is of lower precedence than `+`, so I suggest parentheses.

Comment: @lijie - neither C nor C++ mandate 2s-complement. In some cases, for portability reasons, it may be preferable to use unsigned ints and use the explicit 2s-complement form of ~sgn+1. Of course you'd use unsigned for everything in that case (big integer libraries do this kind of thing). In this case, for portable correctness, I'd say "*must* use -sgn" and try to discourage bit-fiddling - though it's fine if it's just for fun/learning, of course.

Comment: Note - even if your platform *is* 2s-complement (as most if not all are), some recent compilers will exploit the "undefined" in the standard language for optimisation, and generate code that won't do what you expect.

Comment: @steve314: Yes, I agree that 2's complement is not mandated. However, the whole expression (not just the `~sgn+1` part) is premised on 2's complement (otherwise, the conditional cannot be replaced). The suggestion to replace was based on a "1 operation is better than 2 kind of reasoning"; the negation is probably as fast as the addition, so the inversion is wasting time.

Comment: @lijie: The conditional could be replaced even if the platform does not use 2's complement -- see the answers by Paul and EboMike.

Comment: @sven: i agree. however, _even_ both paul's and ebomike's answers depend on -1 being represented as all ones. but as an example, `x += (sgn*2-1)*pow2` removes the conditional. would saying that the multiplication is unavoidable unless some representation of the numbers involved is assumed be a valid statement then?

Comment: Stating the obvious - probably the most common representation of -1 other than/prior to 2s complement was sign-magnitude - the 8 bit -1 would be `10000001` assuming the sign goes in the MSB.

Answer (score 4):

```
mask = sgn - 1; // generate mask: sgn == 0 => mask = -1, sgn == 1 => mask = 0

x = x + (mask & (-pow2)) + (~mask & (pow2)); // use mask to select +/- pow2 for addition
```

Comment: @Sven: no, `&` is a bitwise operator

Comment: There was a conditional when I posted my comment.  And you know this.

Comment: @Sven: nope - look at the edit history if you don't believe me - there was an `|` which I replaced with a `+`, but no conditionals.

Comment: There was `int mask = (sgn == 0) - 1`.  Really.  And you know it's not in the history because quick edits are not in the history.  I feel played games with and suggest deleting all these comments :)

Comment: @Sven: firstly `(sgn == 0)` is **not** a *conditional*, it's a (branchless) *test* . Secondly, I took this out when I re-read the question and saw that sgn could only take values 0 and 1, making the *test* operation unnecessary. So as I said, there never were any conditionals, and no one is plying any games - you just made a simple mistake.

Comment: I call ambiguous - the == is often called a conditional operator, but is clearly not (edit: in itself) a conditional in the sense of selective execution.

Comment: @Steve314: anyone who calls `==` a conditional operator is misguided - its proper name is the *equality operator* or *equal-to operator*. It certainly doesn't imply branching, which is the main issue for performance in this context.

Comment: @Paul:  `sgn == 0` is what I called a conditional, but I comply with your argument that it is not.  At least, I have learned something :)

Comment: @Sven: good for you. I've been programming for around 30 years and I *still* learn new stuff (or get old misconceptions corrected) here on SO and elsewhere, on an almost daily basis. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

```
int subMask = sgn - 1;
x -= pow2 & subMask;
int addMask = -sgn;
x += pow2 & addMask;
```

No guarantees on whether it works or whether this is smart, this is just a random idea that popped into my head.

EDIT: let's make this a bit less readable (aka more compact):

```
x += (pow2 & -sgn) - (pow2 & (sgn-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the interface and replace the multiplication by left shift. (Use exponent instead of pow2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like (from the link)
x += ((pow2 ^ -sgn) + sgn)